# how to get actual height of Grid Row before rendering

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

In my project there are many nested Grids. And mostly rows and columns width is defined as "*" in XAML.
I am trying to expand a particular row(lets say Row1) by seting other row's height to 0, and i am using the .ActualHeight property to get the width of Row1 then its not giving me actual height.
As per I know that is happening because height and width of Grid rows and columns are set on rendering time. 
I searched on net and somebody suggested to use UpdateLayout() method ..but that is also not working for me.
I can not post code snippet because it is very long code.
my project in c#.net wpf.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to do a full layout update, that is you need to call Measure, Arrange and UpdateLayout:

```
    //Make the framework (re)calculate the size of the element
    _Element.Measure(new Size(Double.MaxValue, Double.MaxValue));
    Size visualSize = _Element.DesiredSize;
    _Element.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(0, 0), visualSize));
    _Element.UpdateLayout();
```

_Element being a FrameworkElement (Grid is one).

Answer (score 0):

Solution based on Baboon post worked for me. I needed to animate slide in of collapsed FrameworkElement, what is similar problem of not knowing ActualHeight value.

```
    element.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    element.InvalidateArrange();
    element.UpdateLayout();

    double elementHeight = element.DesiredSize.Height;
    DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation(0, elementHeight, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(animMilisec));
    element.BeginAnimation(Rectangle.HeightProperty, animation);
```

Now before element is rendered I have access to it's final height;